# Allow read/write access to file while blocking everyone else

Tags: c#, .net, file-access, file-security

I have a file that requires a password being written to it.
A process reads a password from a file and writes the password to the file so the user that the process runs under requires access to the file. However I wish to block access to everyone else.
Currently I've tried the following:

```
    WindowsIdentity privilegedUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
SecurityIdentifier everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);
FileSecurity acl = new FileSecurity();
acl.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(everyone, FileSystemRights.Read, AccessControlType.Deny));
acl.PurgeAccessRules(privilegedUser.User);
acl.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule(privilegedUser.User, FileSystemRights.Modify,
    AccessControlType.Allow));
File.SetAccessControl(_mirrorConfigFilePath, acl);
```

However when the process attempts to read the file I'm getting an UnauthorizedAccessException.
I think its because the first rule to deny read access to everyone gets precedence. Anyone any ideas how I can resolve this? Or am I even right in my thinking here?!

Comment: If I remember correctly an empty ACL denies everything by default. So you just need a single allow read entry.

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately any user can still open/read the file.

Comment: There are no rules saying the permissions from parent should propagate to it?

Comment: Not sure Sami what you mean by permissions from parent propagating to it. I am only concerned with one file

Comment: You may only be worried of one file, however if it inherits parent permissions than anything that is not explicitly denied will be allowed.